# How average page load time differs in Google Analytic's and New Relic

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, newrelic, threshold, page-load-time

In one of my website I'm tracking with Google Analytic's and New Relic ?

But Google Analytic's is showing 12 sec and New Relic is showing 9 Sec.

may I know why this difference occurs usually ?

Does it by threshold which is not correct in New Relic and doesn't capture it completely or due to JavaScript which is different in measuring the page load time?

If there are any other factors please let me know in detail?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons as to why your New Relic data and Google Analytics data don't match up. It could come down to how you've set up your segment whitelists in New Relic or even that your time frames do not match up. One important factor to note is that Google Analytics may analyse a subset of your data, not the whole set. If the data you are looking at is based on a [small sample size](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1042498?hl=en), it could well be significantly different from the data provided by New Relic.

Answer (score 0):

Does it really matter?  Both 9 seconds and 12 seconds are horrific.

Use something like webpagetest.org or gtmetrix.com to find out why.